# China: Limitations on frequency of applying for L tourist visa

Tags: visas, china

Is there a limitation on how frequently can you apply for L visa? I intend to go there for 70-80 days at a time and in between be home for a month or two. I am applying in Slovenia (part of EU).

I'm planning to go end of this August till mid November. Then I was thinking of going back before Christmas and staying till beginning of March so I catch Chinese new year, then go back maybe in the beginning or middle of May.

Is this possible? Or let me ask differently, is it very likely to get those visas approved so frequently? Or is it more likely to get further visas approved once you already have some previous visas approved?

Comment: Sooner or later, they will think you are trying to work or live in China, and you are going to start getting refusals. Have you ever considered visiting a different country?

Answer (score 2):

I applied and got an 30 day L visa for China in August 2014, while in the country I got an extension for another 30 days.

Last week (late July 2015) I applied for a new 30 day L visa for China in Hong Kong, the guys at the agency I used said it is likely the request will be refused and they recommended applying for a 15 days visa which will be more likely to be issued. They said the fact that I already spent 60 days last year, could be a problem.

It turned out I got my two entries 30 days each L visa, but the agency guys said I should consider myself very lucky.

It seems at least here in Asia they only issue 30 days L visas.

You are planning to go three times within 12 months for more than 30 days each time. From my experiences here, that will be very difficult.

You should check with the Chinese consulate section in your country and ask them about it. Maybe you can get a 12 month visa with multiple entries.

A second passport may be helpful as well.

I've heard that already having a previous Chinese visa would be helpful, but in my case it was less than a year ago and from what I've been told at the visa agency it is not helpful at all.

P.S. I have a German passport

Comment: Strange. Most of the people tell me there is no limit and of course people at the embassy are not very helpful. They keep sending me premade emails with font size 20, bold and red and links to their site I should read for more information when their site is obviously so bad you can't find or understand anything... Well... I guess I should consider maybe to study Chinese to get a X2 visa. :)